# typescript Triple-Slash Directives reference to html file

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Is there a way I can reference JavaScript variables defined in html file `<script>` tag in my type script class?

I am developing an application in angular2 with typescript which needs some plain JavaScript variables which are declared and assigned in index.html in `<script>`. When I am trying to reference them in my typescript class, I am getting error as below.

without reference getting below error:

```
app/services/Resources.ts(8,41): error TS2339: Property 'Resources' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

When I try to reference index.html it shows below error

```
/// <reference path="../../index.html" />

app/services/Resources.ts(1,1): error TS6054: File 'C:/quickstart/index.html' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '
.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

But what you can do is to declare those variables in a separate `.d.ts` file and then reference that:

```
// AddedVariables.d.ts
interface Window {
    Resources: any[];
}
```

Then simply reference that:

```
/// <reference path="AddedVariables.d.ts" />
```

And then you should be able to use `Resources`.

Comment: let me try that. Thanks for the answer.